# Origin of the phrase "la quinta ..." to denote an undesirable or faraway place

Tags: etimología, modismos, colombia

[The Colombian phrase *la quinta porra* denotes an undesirable or faraway place](http://books.google.com/books?id=e-fPeBQ7NxgC&pg=PA195&dq=%22quinta+porra%22&hl=en&ei=lmDlTo77J-eW2AWMufD_Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22quinta%20porra%22&f=false). For example,

> ¡Váyase a la quinta porra!

conveys the same meaning as

> Go to hell!

The earliest use I could find in a superficial search in Google Books was from 1921 in [Esta sí es bola](http://books.google.com/books?id=mtKvSVE_pqMC&lpg=PA223&dq=%22quinta%20porra%22&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q=%22quinta%20porra%22&f=false) by Tomás Carrasquilla:

> El niño la mandó a la quinta porra.

[Estudios románicos](http://books.google.com/books?ei=KWHlTt--KYSq2QXAoJm1BA&ct=result&id=FnBfAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22quinta+porra%22&q=%22mandar+%22+#search_anchor) from the University of Murcia contains several examples of the form *mandar al quinto ...* or *mandar a la quinta ...* that convey the same meaning:

> Mandar/enviar al quinto infierno
>
> [...]
>
> Irse/mandar a la quinta porra
>
> Irse/mandar a la quinta puñeta
>
> [...]
>
> Irse/mandar al quinto pino

Thus, I ask:

- What is the origin of the common root *mandar al quinto* / *mandar a la quinta*? Is it related to [the circles of Hell in Dante's *Inferno*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_(Dante)#Fifth_Circle_.28Anger.29)?
- Is the common root *mandar al quinto* / *mandar a la quinta* used elsewhere besides Colombia? If so, where and in what form?
- What is the origin of *porra* in the Colombian phrase *la quinta porra*?

---

[La frase colombiana *la quinta porra* denota un sitio lejano o desagradable](http://books.google.com/books?id=e-fPeBQ7NxgC&pg=PA195&dq=%22quinta+porra%22&hl=en&ei=lmDlTo77J-eW2AWMufD_Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22quinta%20porra%22&f=false). Por ejemplo,

> ¡Váyase a la quinta porra!

tiene el mismo significado que

> ¡Váyase al diablo!

The earliest use I could find in a superficial search in Google Books was from 1921 in

El uso más antiguo que encontré en una búsqueda superficial en Google Books fue de 1921 en [Esta sí es bola](http://books.google.com/books?id=mtKvSVE_pqMC&lpg=PA223&dq=%22quinta%20porra%22&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q=%22quinta%20porra%22&f=false) por Tomás Carrasquilla:

> El niño la mandó a la quinta porra.

[Estudios románicos](http://books.google.com/books?ei=KWHlTt--KYSq2QXAoJm1BA&ct=result&id=FnBfAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22quinta+porra%22&q=%22mandar+%22+#search_anchor) de la Universidad de Murcia contiene varios ejemplos de frases que comienzan con *mandar al quinto* o *mandar a la quinta* que parecen tener el mismo significado:

> Mandar/enviar al quinto infierno
>
> [...]
>
> Irse/mandar a la quinta porra
>
> Irse/mandar a la quinta puñeta
>
> [...]
>
> Irse/mandar al quinto pino

Por lo tanto, pregunto:

- ¿Cuál es el origen de la raíz común *mandar al quinto* / *mandar a la quinta*? ¿Existe alguna relación con [los círculos del infierno en *La Divina Comedia* de Dante](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infierno_(La_Divina_Comedia)#Quinto_c.C3.ADrculo_.28Ira_y_Pereza.29)?
- ¿Se usa la raíz común *mandar al quinto* / *mandar a la quinta* en algún lugar fuera de  Colombia? ¿Dónde y en que forma?
- ¿Cuál es el origen de *porra* en la frase colombiana *la quinta porra*?

Comment: En español peninsular también es común (excepto por el quinto infierno, que no lo había oído nunca).

Comment: En Argentina se usa muy poco - yo sólo he oído "quinto infierno" alguna vez.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a common expression in Spain to express something is somewhere far and indeterminate or to send somenone to hell. I've found a [reference about being a derivation from "La quinta forca" (Catalan)](http://m.libertaddigital.com/?op=opinion&id=46413). Please be aware that it's an speculation:

> Jordi Cabanes (Barcelona) aporta una curiosa historia para explicar el origen de la expresión "en el quinto pino" (= un lugar perdido o muy lejano), que coloquialmente se dice también "en el quinto coño":
>
> > A mi entender la expresión "en el quinto coño" es una deriva soez (más fuerte y más expresiva, por lo tanto) de una expresión del castellano de Cataluña "en el quinto pino" que a su vez es una adaptación de la expresión catalana "a la quinta forca" de origen barcelonés.
> >
> > Como era habitual en el sistema penal de la época moderna, los cadalsos de la ciudad se situaban progresivamente en los caminos que se acercaban a la ciudad para que quedase claro a los forasteros que allí se hacía cumplir la ley. El sistema barcelonés contaba con cinco cruces de caminos, desde la plaza del Pi de Barcelona hasta el llamado "de la Trinidad" (hoy un barrio situado en la Meridiana), donde se situaban sendas horcas. Como la responsabilidad de las autoridades se acababa con la ejecución y los cadáveres quedaban expuestos durante muchos días, en la Iglesia del Pi se había fundado una cofradía –la "Confraría de la Sang", de carácter privado­­– cuya misión consistía en dar cristiana sepultura a los ejecutados. Para tal efecto se organizaban periódicas procesiones que, a pie, recorrían la distancia entre la sede y las horcas, recogiendo ("amorosamente" según expresión de una crónica contemporánea) los cadáveres y rezando por la eterna salvación de sus almas. Naturalmente, la horca de la Trinidad caía especialmente lejos y se fue identificando como paradigma de una gran y molesta distancia. La centralidad de Barcelona traspasa la expresión al catalán en general y a su vez al castellano de Cataluña. El motivo del cambio de "horca" a "pino" pertenece, en mi caso, al terreno de las conjeturas. Probablemente se deba a la cacofonía que se produce (al menos para un oído catalán) en "la quinta horca". Aunque no hay que descartar que el instrumento físico de la ejecución no fuese una horca construida, como las que nos suministra cierta iconografía (incluida la popular con el famoso juego de "el ahorcado") sino simplemente una horca natural, y para ello el pino parece un mejor candidato que el roble. Al menos por lo que sé de la flora histórica del plano de Barcelona y del Vallés.